# Displaying Image File Sizes with jsoup and jquery

Tags: java, jquery, html, image, jsoup

I have a java program to download a webpage, parse the webpage for images and display the order in which they are on the website. What i need is for the program to also display the file sizes of each image.

My Code currently:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String url = "http://127.0.0.1";   //Url of webpage
    print("Fetching %s...", url);      //output fetching

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); //getting the document

    Elements media = doc.select("[src]"); //parsing the page for images

    print("\nMedia: (%d)", media.size());
    for (Element src : media) {
        print(" * %s: <%s>", src.tagName(), src.attr("abs:src"));

    }

}
```

Atm this appears as this:

```
<img href="cat.jpg" />
<img href="dog.jpg" />
<img href="horse.jpg" />
```

Is there a way to have the output to look like this?

```
<img href="cat.jpg" /> ---> 54kb
<img href="dog.jpg" /> ---> 74kb
<img href="horse.jpg" /> ---> 102kb
```

thanks
P.s im currently using jsoup however i dont mind using another library if that is what is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `URL` class for this:

```
for( Element element : media )
{
    final String src = element.absUrl("src");

    if( src.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") ) // only needed if you want to check only jpegs
    {
        final URL url = new URL(src);
        final long size = url.openConnection().getContentLength();

        System.out.println(element + " ---> " + size + " byte");
    }
}
```

But this will only show the size in **Byte**!

For a better readability you can ...

- Convert it to *kb*, *mb* etc. by your own
- use [FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#byteCountToDisplaySize%28long%29) of [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/index.html): `FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(size)`

Comment: Do you need to close the url connection? I'm guessing not.